# How to properly say "World's fair"

Tags: vocabulary, usage

I've read that there are a couple of different ways to say "World's fair" including "世界博览会" "世博会“ or “万博”。 Would anyone like to comment on common these terms actual are？ Is saying 世纪博览会 in conversation too formal？

Cheers guys，

Comment: When I went to the world expo, I called it 世博会 and everyone understood it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia:

> 世界博览会（英语：Universal Exposition, World's Fair），又称国际博览会及万国博览会，简称世博会、世博、万博，是一个具国际规模的集会。参展者向世界各国展示当代的文化、科技和产业上正面影响各种生活范畴的成果。

Basically just full term vs. 简称.

世界博览会 get's shortened to 世博会, 世博

万国博览会 get's shortened to 万博

here's some quick data from baidu: (baidu hits, you know...like g-hits)

> 世博会: 百度为您找到相关结果约94,100,000个
>
> 世界博览会: 百度为您找到相关结果约41,300,000个
>
> 万博: 百度为您找到相关结果约68,900,000个 (but seems to have a lot of different meanings)
>
> 万国博览会: 百度为您找到相关结果约2,710,000个
>
> 国际博览会: 百度为您找到相关结果约51,800,000个

世博会 is obviously your best bet. (that's what everyone was calling it when it was in Shanghai...09(?))

Going around saying 世纪博览会 instead of 世博会 would be like someone going around saying the World Wrestling Entertainment instead of WWE or National Football League instead of NFL...